# How to use HttpServletRequest object received as a method parameter into a new thread declared in the same method

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jax-rs, weblogic

i have the follow code:

```
public void doSomething(HttpServletRequest requestContext){
     new RequestProcessor(requestContext).process();
}

private class RequestProcessor implements Runnable {


public RequestProcessor(HttpServletRequest request) 
  {
    this.request = request;
  }

  private void process() {
    new Thread(this).start();
  }

  public void run() {
    System.out.println(request.toString())  //ignore the logic here, is only a example...
  }
}
```

but when the Request processor is instantiated i'm getting the follow exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread local value in scope for proxy of class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy
```

i need to send the complete HttpservletRequest to the thread, exist a way to do this ?

Comment: Is important mentionate that the class that contains this code are a Stateless EJB anotated with @Stateless...

Comment: Don't do it. Pass needed values down into it.